# use Flink SQL multiple case when

Tags: flink-sql

I am using Flink SQL generate explain.

```
select case when count(*)>1 then '11' end as query,case when src_ip='6' then '22' end as query from table
```

but found exception,it say

```
Expression 'src_ip' is not being grouped
```

when I alter count(*) to others,like event_name...

```
select case when event_name>'test' then '11' end as query,case when src_ip='6' then '22' end as query from table
```

It is OK,can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query that doesn't work isn't valid SQL. You can't apply an aggregation (such as `count(*)`) without having a `GROUP BY` so that the aggregation has something to aggregate over.